# Bloquear célula após preenchimento

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou tentando melhorar a planilha de controle da empresa que trabalho, mas estou tendo problema.

Temos que registrar a ligação de um cliente, já consegui fazer para a planilha preencher a Data e Hora automaticamente após preencher o campo Nome. O que quero agora é proteger os campos Data e Hora nesse momento, para que não possa ser alterado. O que está acontecendo é que em algumas linhas o excel bloqueou a linha inteira. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Esse é o código que fiz até aqui.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Alvo As Range)

     Dim limite_maximo As Integer

  limite_maximo = 4000 ' limite ultima linha

  If Alvo.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Alvo) Then Exit Sub

    ' faz nada se mais de uma célula modificada ou se deu delete

  If Alvo.Column = 5 And Alvo.Row >= 4 And Alvo.Row <= limite_maximo Then

    ' o if acima seta onde vai iniciar e o range e = 5 (coluna), row (linha = 4)

    ' desliga captura do evento change

  Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' muda a célula E da linha correspondente

  ' Desprotege

  ActiveSheet.Unprotect

  Alvo.Offset(0, -1).Value = Time() ' Registra a hora (A = 0, D = 3)
  Alvo.Offset(0, -2).Value = Date   ' Registra a data (A = 0, E = 4)
  
  Linha = Alvo.Row
  
  Range("C" & Linha).Locked = True
  Range("e" & Linha).Locked = True

  ' Protege
  ActiveSheet.Protect

  ' religa a captura de eventos
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Essa é a planilha

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você deve inserir `Locked = False` em todas as células da planilha somente uma vez, com o seguinte código:

```
Sub Destravar_Tudo()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False
End Sub
```

Pois por padrão em `.Protect`, todas as células estão com `.locked = True`

Depois, ao travar cada célula, a planilha é protegida com `ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True, DrawingObjects:=False`, como pode ser visto no código abaixo:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Alvo As Range)
    Dim limite_maximo As Long, linha As Long
    'Tratar Erros
    On Error GoTo sair

    limite_maximo = 4000                         ' limite ultima linha

    If Alvo.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Alvo) Then Exit Sub

    ' faz nada se mais de uma célula modificada ou se deu delete
    If Alvo.Column = 5 And Alvo.Row >= 4 And Alvo.Row <= limite_maximo Then
        ' o if acima seta onde vai iniciar e o range e = 5 (coluna), row (linha = 4)
        ' desliga captura do evento change
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        ' muda a célula E da linha correspondente
        ' Desprotege

        ActiveSheet.Unprotect

        Alvo.Offset(0, -1).Value = Time()        ' Registra a hora (A = 0, D = 3)
        Alvo.Offset(0, -2).Value = Date          ' Registra a data (A = 0, E = 4)

        linha = Alvo.Row

        Range("C" & linha & ":E" & linha).Cells.Locked = True

        ' Protege
        ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True, DrawingObjects:=False
    End If
sair:
    ' religa a captura de eventos
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Ou para travar manualmente cada linha:

```
Sub manual_linha()
    Dim linha As Long
    linha = 4
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Range("C" & linha & ":E" & linha).Cells.Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True, DrawingObjects:=False
End Sub
```

No exemplo, a linha 4 está sendo utilizada, portanto, o intervalo de `C4:E4`

Comment: Daniel, obrigado pela ajuda.

Fiz como disse, mas houve um problema. Ele acabou travando também outras linhas, como na imagem ele travou da E7 até a H7... não entendo porque ele trava outras células que eu não indiquei.

indiquei apenas dessas colunas Range("C" & linha & ":E" & linha).Cells.Locked = True

Sabe porque isso ocorre?

Comment: Estranho. Num teste que fiz não trava as outras

Comment: Ele não travou todas, só travou algumas que não estavam na seleção do vba. Pode me mandar o arquivo que você fez para eu ver se tem algum erro no meu?